# Choose the number of items shown per page Vue/Laravel Pagination

Tags: laravel-5, select, vue.js, pagination, dropdown

I am working on a site using vuejs for the frontend and Laravel backend where I am implementing a pagination functionality. The goal is to have the user to be able to choose the number of items to show per page using a dropdown box. Note: I am using paginate(perPage,10). So I am trying to work around how I can get the 'perPage' from Vue frontend and refresh the page with the new perPage value. Thanks in advance!!

```
**$projects = DB::table('projects')
            ->select("projects.*", "project_countries.project_id",
                DB::raw("(GROUP_CONCAT(countries.name SEPARATOR ',')) as 'countries'"))
            ->join('project_countries', 'projects.project_id', '=', 'project_countries.project_id')
            ->join('countries', 'project_countries.country_id', '=', 'countries.id')
            ->groupBy('project_countries.project_id')
            ->orderBy('project_countries.project_id')
            ->paginate($request->get('per_page', 10));**
```

Here is my data on Vue:

```
data() {
        return {
            projects: [],
            project: {
                id: '',
                project_id: '',
                title: '',
                amount: '',
                countries: '',
                gcf_date: ''
            },
            project_id: '',
            pagination: {},
            edit: false,
            perPage: 10,
      }
```

Comment: cant you just make a parameter of `perPage` and have it reactive inside Vue? This question shows no code at all...

Comment: edit your main question and use backticks ` to format your code or triple backticks  for a code block

Comment: hey I edited my question